# is it better to say final type variable or say final variable according to memory management

Tags: dart

i know that `var` in many languages takes more ram than saying the explicit type
but it's different in final situation.

```dart
final i = 10; // without type
final int i = 10; // with type
```

// which is better? or there is no difference at all ?

i searched a little and saw lint [always_specify_types](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html), so it's in dart effective dart, but does this include final variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned, those two lines are identical. The compiler infers the type from the right hand side. (You should even be able to hover over the `i` in the first line in the IDE and it will show you that it's an `int`.)

So, now it's a matter of style. Do you prefer the Flutter style approach, or the [omit local types](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html) approach?

Comment: so it's just styling ? ,, no effect on performance or ram or anything ?

Comment: Correct. No difference.